# Should we have the ability to accept multiple answers as solutions and rate their quality?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

I found that different answers are sometimes answering a question, even different methods are used and the execution speed is varying.

Did you ever think about the ability to accept more than one answer as a solution?

Could the quality of answers be rated with e.g. a quality scale (0: not useful, 10: excellent solution)?

Comment: There's a nifty little quality scale already implemented. It uses votes.

Answer (score 4):

> I found that different answers are sometimes answering a question,
>   even different methods are used and the execution speed is varying.

But, the one which actually helps the OP (the most) is supposed to be accepted.

And the other answers which are correct and also been helpful can/will be rewarded with upvotes.

> Did you ever think about to be able to accept more than one answer as
>   a solution?

Totally personal opinion. I think it would create chaos for the others viewing the post, as well as open doors to more sock-puppeting.

> Could the quality of answers be rated with e.g. a quality scale (0:
>   nor useful, 10: excellent solution)?

The vote count of the answer does exactly that.